# Help building an SQL query for products with custom options

Tags: custom-options, sql, query

Need help making a query which returns the Product ID of all products which have custom options

Comment: You want a SQL query direct from the database or through Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento:

```
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection();
$options->addFieldToSelect('product_id');
$options->getSelect()->distinct(true);

foreach ($options as $option) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($option->getProductId());
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.`product_id` FROM `catalog_product_option` AS `main_table`
```

Comment: you can add a `Distinct` also in the select to remove duplicates.

Comment: This worked great. Curious if you could advise how to make the query more elaborate so it returns all product id AND product name AND what custom options are available for that product. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use the below query

```
    echo  $Sql= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection()
-> addFieldToSelect('product_id')->getSelect()
            ->distinct(true);

echo $Sql->__toString();
```

use `getSelect()` function for getting the sql query and distinct to get `distinct` data